# Conditional Cell Template in ui grid angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I need to display the text in a cell as a link based on a status or as a plain text.
If the status is 'Deleted' the name should be displayed as plain text or else as an hyperlink. Below are my grid options. I am always getting it as hyperlink. Someone please help me correct my cell template so that I am getting it correct.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'ProjectDetails',
    columnDefs: [
    { field: 'Id', displayName: 'ID', visible: false },
    { displayName: 'Name', width: 200, cellTemplate: '<div> {{row.entity.ProjectStatus}} != Deleted </div>' ? '<div><a href="http://################ID={{row.entity.Id}}">{{row.entity.Name}}</a></div>' : '<div> {{row.entity.Status}}</div>' },
    { field: 'Expense', displayName: 'Operating Expense', width: 185, cellFilter: 'noFractionCurrency' },        
    { field: 'Status', displayName: 'Status', width: 150 }
    ]
};
```

Comment: Why don't you accept your solution ?

Answer (score 2):

`ng-if` helped me.

```
cellTemplate: "<a target='_blank' ng-if=\"row.entity.Status != 'Deleted'\" 
href='#########?ID={{row.entity.Id}}'>{{row.entity.Name}}</a><div ng-
if=\"row.entity.Status == 'Deleted'\">{{row.entity.Name}}</div>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this with `ngShow`.

```
var cellTemplate = "<div ng-show='row.entity.Status !== 'Deleted''><a href='#####{{row.entity.Id}}'>{{row.entity.Name}}</a></div><div ng-show='row.entity.Status === 'Deleted''>{{row.entity.Status}}</div>"
```

Comment: That does not help. It shows both the Name both as the link and as the text in each row irrespective of the status.

Comment: It only displays a link if `row.entity.Status !== 'Deleted'`.  Check your JSON.  There are two div's using two distinct `ng-show`, modify them to fit your needs.  Sorry for blind-coding errors.

Comment: Not sure still had no luck with ngShow.

Answer (score 0):

I just added href for Status -deleted and plain text for non-deleted option.

```
var cellTemplate: "<a target='_blank' ng-if="row.entity.Status !=\ 'Deleted\'" 
href='#########>{{row.entity.Name}}</a><div ng-
if="row.entity.Status == \'Deleted\'">{{row.entity.Name}}</div>"
```